# LC347: Top K Frequent Elements; final result returns an extra element in list/array

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, hash

Leetcode 347 in Python, snippet of my code:

```
class Solution:
    def topKFrequent(self, nums: List[int], k: int) -> List[int]:
        dictionary = {}
        freq = [[] for i in range(len(nums) + 1)]

        for num in nums:
            dictionary[num] = dictionary.get(num, 0) + 1

        for k, v in dictionary.items():
            freq[v].append(k)
        
        result = []
        for i in range(len(freq)-1, 0, -1):
            for n in freq[i]:
                result.append(n)
                if len(result) == k:
                    return result
```

In the case of nums = [1,1,1,2,2,3], result list should return [1,2], but my result list is returning [1,2,3].

I found that in the following for loops, if I change the variable names to match each other, then the solution returns the correct answer.

By changing **k** to **num**, to match the variables of the for loops:

```
        for num in nums:
            dictionary[num] = dictionary.get(num, 0) + 1
        # num was originally k, as observed in the code snippet above
        for num, v in dictionary.items():
            freq[v].append(num)
```

Why is this so? Aren't separate for-loops independent of iterator variables?

Comment: The `k` in `for k, v` shadows the argument to your function `k`. That's why it works when you change the `k` to `num` -- it's not `num` specifically, you can choose _any_ other name than `k`

Comment: In situations like this, stepping through your code in a debugger is very helpful. You're bound to realize when you reach the final loop that `k` has changed. Then it's easy enough to find _where_ it changes

Comment: @pho OH i just saw that k is one of the parameters in the function! Thank you so much lol, the leetcode grind is slowly rotting my brain